# What was the first English acronym?

Tags: acronyms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When did the use of acronyms begin?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/33532/when-did-the-use-of-acronyms-begin)

For whatever reason, people love to *claim* that words are acronyms: *wog*, *snob*, *fuck*, *news*, *posh*; the oldest example I know of comes 1668 when five Privy Councillors (Clifford, Arlington, Buckingham, Ashley-Cooper, and Lauderdale) were accused of forming a CABAL (the word, as every Madonna fan knows, really comes from ancient Hebrew *kabbalah*).

The actual habit of coining acronyms seems to be much newer.  All the real acronyms I can think of are either technical (*scuba*, *radar*, *laser*) or political (*gestapo*, *Nato*) innovations from the 20th Century.

What was the first acronym in English? Was there any developed as something other than a name for a new invention? And (if you really want to make me happy) is there one that is so old that it has fallen into disuse?

Comment: [When did the use of acronyms begin?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/33532/when-did-the-use-of-acronyms-begin)

Comment: @Tsuyoshi Ito -- thanks, the question is similar there but the accepted answer is completely wrong!  It talks about Icthys (an initialism that happened to match an existing word) and INRI (an initialism that isn't a word at all).  I'm looking for initialisms that became words in their own right.

Comment: You actually want acronyms that became words in their own right, but you're asking for the first acronym -- can you maybe clarify your question to include this?

Comment: @simchona -- by definition, an acronym is a word in its own right.  If you're still spelling out an abbreviation (e.g. "GPA" or "USA" or "e.g."), that ain't an acronym.

Comment: @Malvolio You are precisely wrong. [The *primary* and still perfectly functional definition of acronym is an initialism whose letters are pronounced separately](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/1844). Your sumpsimus is just a mumpsimus.

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto It's not helpful to shut off discussion here when *a* that discussion was arbitrarily closed despite having straightforward research possibilities and *b* when it was about all acronyms and this is about specifically English ones.

Comment: In any case, [this is a better discussion than the one presently linked](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/268164/when-did-initial-origin-words-pronounced-as-words-start-happening) and it seems to have the answer to OP's question: *abjad* was being used by the late 18th century.